# Text at the edge of a table

Tags: tables

I have made a big table in L-form, and I was wondering if there is any way in Latex to write at the ege of the L where there is nothing in the table. See the following illustration:

[image]

So the idea is to save space in continuing the regular document when there is space left in a flating table. I know it usually looks bad, but in case of a huge (rather high) table it might not. I hope you got the idea.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[tbp]
\centering
\caption{This is a huge table. Guess what the magic number is...} 
\label{magic numbers}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{This} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{is} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{is} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{This} \\
\midrule \multicolumn{4}{l}{Magic numbers} \\ \multicolumn{1}{l}{A} & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42& -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{A} & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42  \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{A} & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 &&& \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 &&&\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 &&& \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 &&& \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 &&&\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 &&& \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 &&& \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 &&& \\ 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated note: you may want to use math mode for all the numbers, as it stands the 'minus signs' are hyphens. `\begin{tabular}{*{9}{>{$}c<{$}}}` will create 9 centered columns where each cell will be in math mode (I borrowed from Werner's answer and modified it). You'll need `\multicolumn` for text cells. Requires `\usepackage{array}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the example below I've set the text inside a `par`agraph `box`. The `\parbox` is aligned/anchored at the `b`ottom, has a height of `0pt` (so as to not influence other lines inside the `tabular`, and starts from the `b`ottom moving upwards. The width is calculated to be exactly 3 columns wide (3 entries of `-54.42` stored in box 1), plus the remaining `\tabcolsep`s of between the columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script

\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \caption{This is a huge table. Guess what the magic number is...} 
  \label{ovbdiffx3to5}
  \setbox1=\hbox{-54.42}
  \small\begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
    \toprule 
    & This & is & is & This \\
    \midrule \multicolumn{4}{l}{Magic numbers} \\
    A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42\\ 
    B & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
    C & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42& -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
    $D$ & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
    A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42  \\ 
    B & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
    C & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
    $D$ & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
    A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
    B & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\ 
    C & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 &&& \\ 
    $D$ & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 &&&\\ 
    B & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 &&& \\ 
    C & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 &&& \\ 
    $D$ & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 &&&\\ 
    B & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 &&& \\ 
    C & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 &&& \\ 
    $D$ & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 &&&
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{\relax\llap{\parbox[b][0pt][b]{\dimexpr3\wd1+3\tabcolsep}{%
      Here is some text. It is enough to span multiple lines, filling in from
      the bottom upwards.%
    }}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If the contents of your `tabular` contains numbers, use math mode to set the numbers (as in `$-54.42$`) since it will provide the appropriate spacing of the unary operator `-`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach which uses Werner's method to calculate the appropriate width. (At least, I think it does though I don't understand TeX's dimensions well enough to be certain.)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[tbp]
\centering
\caption{This is a huge table. Guess what the magic number is...}
\label{ovbdiffx3to5}
\setbox1=\hbox{-54.42}
\newlength{\mycols}
\setlength{\mycols}{\dimexpr3\wd1+3\tabcolsep}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{This} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{is} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{is} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{This} \\
\midrule \multicolumn{4}{l}{Magic numbers} \\ \multicolumn{1}{l}{A} & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42& -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{A} & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{A} & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 & -54.42& -54.42& -54.42 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 & %
  \multicolumn{3}{p{\mycols}}{\multirow{8}{\mycols}{Here is some text. It is enough to span multiple lines, filling in from the centre upwards and downwards.}}\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 &&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 &&& \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 &&& \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 &&&\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{B} & -54.42 & -54.42  & -54.42  & -54.42 &&& \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{C} & 54.42 & 54.42  & 54.42  & 54.42 &&& \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$D$} & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 & -54.42 &&& \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: Using multirow to place text spanning 3 columns within a table]

I think this might look a little less odd if the text used space to the right of the table as well so it did not look *part* of the table. However, I can't get that to work without giving up booktabs. I also wondered about using \cmidrule{6-8} after the preceding line but that introduces additional vertical spacing so it messes up the rest of the table.

Comment: also thanks a lot for your entry. You are correct with the space to the right, but in this case the table pretty much fills the whole width of a page, so the solution is fine!